# How to use mod_rewrite to only allow files without .php extension

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i am using this code in the .htaccess-File to rewrite for example /home to /home.php

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

but how can i do this and at the same time when the server gets a request for /home.php
rewrite it so the file will not be found. I only want to allow access with /home and
not with /home.php but still use the file with it's extension.

Using this .htaccess works in general:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404_error.php

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \.php[\s?/] [NC]
RewriteRule \.php$ - [NC,R=404,L]
```

But when a request that should throw 404 uses for example /whatever the custom 404 error page gets loaded. But with /whatever.php i get this:

```
The requested URL /test/whatever.php was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an
ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

Any idea how to solve this 500 error?

P.S.: Same thing without php-extension "ErrorDocument 404 /404_error"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule to block `.php` requests:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \.php[\s?/] [NC]
RewriteRule \.php$ - [NC,R=404,L]
```

Comment: Works first of all, but with this i also have "ErrorDocument 404 /404_error.php" in my .htaccess, i get an 500 Error for a
bad request with a php-extension, same thing with "ErrorDocument 404 /404_error". Any idea how to solve this 500 Error?

Comment: I can look into that if you post your full htaccess by editing your question.